# Calculating how much of a timeframe falls between two times (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a SSRS report, in the report I have a table with
Start time, Work Time (Duration), Travel Time (Duration)

I'm working out and 'End Time' using the start time and durations

However I also need to work out the below
Hours worked between 0600 - 0800
Hours worked between 1700 - 2200
Hours worked between 2200 - 0600

And have no idea where to even begin

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the dataset, some sample data and the expected output? Have a look at the help page: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set up all the logical steps.  To answer the question of "How many hours of my duration fall between 0600 and 0800?"  there are several sub-questions which, on answering will give you the necessary values to calculate your answer:

**Does the time period overlap 0600-0800?**
Or, is the Start Time before 0800 and the End Time after 0600?

**If no, your answer is 0.**
Or, return 0.

**If yes, does the time period start before 0600, so you have to ignore some time?**
Or, the start time of your calculation is the greater of your Start Time and 0600.

**Then, does the time period end after 0800, so you have to ignore some time?**
Or, the end time of your calculation is the lesser or your End Time and 0800.

---

**Put it all together in the language of your choice:**

```
If StartTime <= 0800 and EndTime >= 0600
    calculate time between
            if StartTime < 0600
                0600
            else
                StartTime
        and 
            if EndTime > 0800
                0800
            else
                EndTime
else
    0
```

Comment: So the logic is sound and works in VB however when trying to figure it out in SSRS as below

`=iif((Fields!Mon_Start_Secs.Value <= 28800) AND (Fields!Mon_End_secs.Value =>21600),(iif(Fields!Mon_Start_Secs.Value < 21600,21600,Fields!Mon_Start_Secs.Value))+(iif(Fields!Mon_End_secs.Value > 28800,28800,Fields!Mon_End_secs.Value)),0)`

I get an Expression expected error BC30201

Comment: @MichaelAuty  Why would you do this in an SSRS expression and not your source query?